# Python: String Slicing in a loop

Tags: python, string

Am trying to slice the following string but my Code doesn't return anything past the second loop.

```
s = "93011NULL                5011005874          A0000000000010000000000001JKL00000000NULL                                              00000000A63"

d = [5,20,20,1,16,9,3,8,50,8,1,2]

start = 0
for x in d:
    print(s[start:x])
    start += x
```

When I run that code, I only get:

```
43011
NULL
```

The rest ten loops print "" i.e. empty strings. Ideally it should loop and slice that string into pieces given the string lengths given in variable d.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `d` in your code?

Comment: oops. had missed some code. D is a list. I've corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're making slices with the second index larger than the first. For the given values of `d`, your slices go as follows:

First iteration: 0,5

Second iteration: 5,20

Third iteration: 25,20 <-- this is where the problem is.

Note that this is because you just keep adding to `start`, so it keeps getting larger and larger.

EDIT: I just realized you may be misinterpreting the Python slice syntax. The second item is not the length of the slice; rather, it's the index of the first element **not** included in the slice.

If you want to partition the string (i.e. have a set of slices with no overlap such that their concatenation is equal to the original string), instead of using `+=`, just use `=`, and set up `d` so that each value in `d` is the index at which you wish a cut to be made. (Note that these indexes must be in increasing order.)

Alternatively, if you want each value in `d` to represent the size of each slice in the partition, use the following code:

```
for x in d:
    print s[start:start+x]
    start += x
```

Comment: You put a comma instead of colon for the slice so I corrected it for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 1**

For your specific problem, the solution looks like this:

```
s = "93011NULL                5011005874          A0000000000010000000000001JKL00000000NULL                                              00000000A63"
d = [5,20,20,1,16,9,3,8,50,8,1,2]

# Convert sizes to indexes
d = [sum(d[:i+1]) for i in range(len(d))]

splits = [s[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+d, d+[None])]

print splits
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
['93011', 'NULL                ', '5011005874          ', 'A', '0000000000010000', '000000001', 'JKL', '00000000', 'NULL                                              ', '00000000', 'A', '63', '']
```

---

If you need to slice, why not try this...

```
>>> s = 'AA111-99XYZ '

>>> d = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11]

>>> [s[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+d, d+[None])]

['AA', '11', '1', '-99', 'XYZ', ' ']
```

**Explanation**

`zip` takes as argument multiple lists and makes a list of sets taking i'th element from each input list.

```
>>> zip(d, d)
[(2, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5), (8, 8), (11, 11)]
```

We need `[(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (5, 8), (8, 11), (11, None)]`. So, the list elements need to be shifted an index.

```
>>> [0] + d
[0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11]

>>> d + [None]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 11, None]
```

Now we call `zip`

```
>>> zip([0] + d, d + [None])
[(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (5, 8), (8, 11), (11, None)]
```

Next, we call `s[i:j]` which will give a slide from index `i to j-1`.

```
>>> s[0:2]
'AA'
>>> s[2:4]
'11'
```

So, we create a list comprehension to generate a list of slices for each entry in the zip output.

```
[ s[i:j] for i, j in zip([0] + d, d + [None]) ]
```

which is equivalent to

```
[ s[i:j] for i, j in [(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, 5), (5, 8), (8, 11), (11, None)] ]
```

Last part, `s[i:None]` is same as `s[i:]`

Comment: The code actually isn't fine. Refer to Kyle Strand's answer.

Comment: The original code isn't correct, but this solution's kind of elegant.

Comment: @AtozToa I like what you've done there but I really don't get it. Can you explain your solution? Or post a link to somewhere I can read about it? Thanks.

Comment: @lukik I have added an explanation...

Comment: @ATOzTOA thanks! I will definitely try and get my head around this interesting code.